# Should I save the context object in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ado.net

I am new to Entity Framework, so forgive me if the question seems basic. I am wondering, is it better to save the context object created by Entity Framework to use it over the application, or I should create a new context object each time I want to access/modify the database?

To formulate the question differently, will there by any performance problems if I create the context object too frequently? Or will there by any database issues (e.g. locking the database) if I keep the context object alive over the life time of the application?

Answer (score 4):

Both EF, and Linq2SQL contexts are designed for a short lifetime.
If you are serving web pages, usually the best practice is use one context per HTTP request.

But i think this applies to other ORMs as well. All do use some sort of caching, and object change tracking that can result is weird bugs if the context lives for too long, or shared between requests.

Edit: things can be different if you are writing a thick client app.